# Table of contents - filled dots not to unnumbered chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

I'm trying to create table of contents with hyperref and dot-filled lines. However I don't want them to be in unnumbered chapters. I couldn't find the solution for my problem from similar questions so I decided to create the a one. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Experiments}

\section{sec 1}

\section{sec 2}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It can easily be done with the `\titlecontents` command, from package `titletoc`, which come with `titlesec`. See p. 14 of  titlesec documentation.

Comment: Follow-up question: What if I want dots also away from first numbered chapter introduction? (This is actually the problem I need to solve)

Comment: This is probably harder. Are you sure your introduction has to be numbered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your MWE, it was a great help. Try the following changes, less any of my typos, to your MWE after the line `\usepackage{hyperref}`

```
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapdotsep}
    {\protect\cftnodots}}
\chapter*{Abstract}
 % then as before until
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapdotsep}
    {\protect\cftdotsep}}
\chapter{Introduction}
```

The first `\addtocontents` tells the ToC that chapters have no dotted leaders. The second `\addtocontents` tells the ToC to use the normal dotted leaders for chapters. Any fragile commands in the argument of `\addtocontents` have to be `\protect` ed otherwise there will be strange results.

Comment: Thanks for the GREAT answer, it did the thing! The only tiny problem exists anymore. Font of the dots for the chapters is different (bigger and bolded) compared to the font of the dots for the sections. Probably I have to use same font but I don't know how

Comment: Now I found the solution and I will share it here if someone will be in same situation as I was. So, to show dots in toc after chapter xxx with same font as in section: \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}}. Again thanks to Peter Wilson for the great answer. Without it I would have never find the solution!